# How do I submit a form and make a call to ebay's API at the same time while using data from the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm building a ruby on rails application that allows users to select the max price they want to spend on on a product in a form which is then stored and inserted into ebay's item filter which is part of their api. However, I have to submit the form first, then call the function to execute the api, how can I combine these two steps?

This is the code for the form which has a select tag for the user to select their max price as well as a submit button which works fine. I tried to add the onclick option and call the showItems() function which makes the ebay API call, but it does not return the items.

```
    <%= form_tag do |f| %>
      <div>     
        <%= select_tag "max_price", "<option>10</option><option>20</option>".html_safe %>
        <%=submit_tag("Submit filter", id: "form_button", onclick: 'showItems();' ) %>
      </div>
    <% end %>


<!-- this is where the list of items will appear -->
<div id="results"></div>

<!-- this variable is for grabbing the @max_price variable when the form is submitted-->
<% @max_price = params[:max_price]%>


<script>

   [...ebay api taken out to simplify question]

   //this is the function that calls the api and is what I want to call in my form with my form data  
   function showItems() {

    console.log('You are in the show items function')
    // Submit the request
    s=document.createElement('script'); // create script element
    s.src= url;
    document.body.appendChild(s);
   }

</script>
```